# How to properly import classes: Http Client from Apache Commons

Tags: java, eclipse, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm starting to learn java and am having an incredibly hard time working with the Http methods that I thought I obtained from Apache commons. I'm trying to make a class that can make a bitcoin trade on btc-e.com.

I downloaded the HTTPComponents client, then included all the .jar files in the buildpath for my project. But for some reason, eclipse is still not recognizing some of these methods. Specifically, HttpUtils is not recognized.

Can someone walk me through a step-by-step procedure of how to include these classes properly in my code? I'm really new to this and have spent 6+ hours trying to figure this out.

This is the gist of what I have:

```
public static int Buyy(double rate, double amount){

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    long nonce = ( now.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
    String api_key= " ";
    String api_secret = " ";
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.btc-e.com/tapi");

    try {
        // Add data
        HashMap params = new HashMap();
        params.put("method", "Trade");
        params.put("pair", "btc_usd");
        params.put("type", "buy");
        params.put("rate", rate);
        params.put("amount", amount);
        params.put("nonce", nonce);

        HashMap headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Contnent-type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.put("key", api_key);
        headers.put("sign", api_secret);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }


}
```

Specifically, the errors I'm getting are:
-The import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpResponse cannot be resolved

-HttpResponse cannot be resolved to a type

-The type org.apache.http.HttpResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

-The type org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I take this to mean that I'm not importing all the files that I need to? I'm not sure how to do that though--and I'm not sure which ones I need. I'm really lost.

THANKS! I really appreciate any help. I'm using Eclipse.

This is what I'm already importing:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Comment: Which IDE do you use and how do you compile your code ?

Comment: I'm using eclipse. It was in eclipse that i added the .jar files to the buildpath

Comment: Move the apache JAR files to top of the list in "Order and Export" tab of Java build path. There may be some conflict with the JAR files included in build path.

Comment: Also can you list down the JAR files in the build path

Answer (score 2):

For `HttpResponse` I think the import should be

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
```

and not

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpResponse;
```

The second one does not seem to exist in the API.

Check also that you have included the JARs of both HttpCore and HttpClient in your build path.

Comment: Thanks! i still hadn't added the jars from httpCore. That got rid of most of the error messages, but I'm still getting an erorr for this line:
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
The error says: The method execute(HttpPost) is undefined for the type HttpClient

Comment: @adamjts Did you fix the import of `HttpResponse` ?

Comment: yeah i changed the import to the one that you suggested. These are all the apache imports:
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

Comment: Your import of `HttpClient` is not correct: you have `import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;` and it should be `import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;`. Did you mix JAR files from Apache Commons and Apache HttpComponents in your project ? Don't include too much JAR files in the build path, you need only httpcore and httpclient.